# How to update a value with reducer via text input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-reducers

I would like to update the value of a variable in the reducer. In the app the user can type the username in a text input field in one screen. The reducer should update this state so that I can output it on a different screen. Right now I'm using useState but I'd like to use the reducer instead. I'm new to coding and I'm really struggling with this so I hope someone can help me.

The reducer:

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const userSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'user',
        initialState: " ",
        reducers: {
            setUser: (state = initialState, action) => {
                ???
            },
        }
    });

    export const {setUser} = userSlice.actions;
    export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Code in the screen with useState:

```
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");   
    const onValueChange = (number) => setUser(number); 
    const onButtonHandler = () => setUserName(user);

       <View style= {globalStyles.containerInput}>
          <TextInput 
             style= {globalStyles.input} 
             maxLength={20} 
             minLegth={10} 
             keyboardType="number-pad"
             value={user}
             onChangeText={onValueChange}
          />
       </View>
       <View style= {globalStyles.containerButton}>
          <Pressable 
             style={globalStyles.button}
             onPress={onButtonHandler}
          >
          </Pressable>
       </View>
```

Comment: your code is not readable. can you add your full code, like what are you doing with "onValueChange".

Comment: This is my full code for this. With the code I have now I use `useState()` to get the username from the text input and I can output the username with `{userName}`. But I'd like to use the reducer instead so that I can apply `dispatch(setUser()`and use `userValue` (via `const userValue = useSelector((state) => state.user.value`) anywhere in the app because I use react navigation and I can't use `userName` or `user` in a different screen.